# After performSegueWithIdentifier App crashes with Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash

Today I updated Xcode to 11.2. Since then the app crashes with Exception Type: **EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)**. The app crashes only when run with Xcode on a real device. If installed with TestFlight it does not crash. If run on simulator it also doesn't crash.

It crashes after the following code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueName" sender:nil];
```

The new `UIViewController` is never shown.

What I tried so far:

- Recreated the segue
- Dispatched the line on the main queue
- There is one outlet and one action - both are connected to the correct `UIViewController`

Neither of the above helped. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @user3079872 If I remember correctly this was an Xcode 11.2 bug and disappeared when updating to a newer version or downgrading to an older one. It appeared when trying to reach screens made in storyboard having an UITextView. Another approach would be to write the UITextView in code to avoid the crash but it seems like an overkill.

Comment: Cheers! It turns out my issue was nothing to do with the segue. But thank you very much for answering!